# Weird activecell.offset output

Tags: vba, excel, offset

```
Sub Link()


    Dim Turbidity As Long
    Dim RawTurbidity As Range


    'Sets variables Turbidity being the ActiveCell and RawTurbidity referring to the last captured cell in raw sheets'
    Turbidity = ActiveCell.Row
    Set RawTurbidity = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("C4").End(xlDown)


    'The formula assigning the last captured cell in Raw sheets to the active cell '
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(Turbidity, 4), Sheet1.Cells(Turbidity, 4)).Formula = RawTurbidity

End Sub
```

So this is the code I have and currently it does what it's suppose to do. We have two sheets atm sheet1 and Raw Data An instrument spits out data into column C of Raw data starting wtih C4 and going all the way down. The current code I wrote in essence paste the newest value the instrument spits out to the active cell in sheet1. I have a code on Raw Data that runs the macro only when a change is made to column C4 and lower. And it works exactly how I want it to however...

my question or issue is that when I add activecell.offset(1,0).select in order to have the activecell automatically go to the next row in sheet1 without me moving the mouse the macro copies and paste the same data into the next 4 cells. If I have the intrument spit out the data again than this time it occupies the next 6 rows with the same data.

Comment: Why are you setting the `Formula` of the cell to a value (`RawTurbidity`)?

Comment: Do you really need to use `ActiveCell` - is it a random cell on the 1st sheet? There's probably a better way, avoiding it. You can simplify the line with two instances of `Sheet1.Cells(Turbidity, 4)` - to just `Sheet1.Cells(Turbidity, 4).Value = RawTurbidity.Value`.

Comment: @PeterT -I assume that is a remnant of the macro recorder

Comment: find your last rows each time you come into the sub, one for sheet 1, and the other for the Raw Data sheet.  Then simply assign the value form one cell to the other, "like a copy".  Try it out.  I compiled it but I did not set it up to test it, answer below.

Comment: @BigBen yes unfortunately at times the calculations need to go in random cells. Hence the activecell. I mean the formula I posted(which I simplified by your instructions) does exactly what I want. My issue is making it so the activecell points automatically to the next row after copying the data is the issue. ActiveCell.Offset(1,0) when inserted into the current formula simply copies the data into the next 4 cells. When really I just want the cursor to move down 1 without copying anything.

Answer (score 1):

Joe B, I think you are making this harder than it is.
Last value in a sheet column gets copied to the next open row in a specified column on another sheet?  Is that right?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Link()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsRaw As Worksheet

    Dim ws1LastRow As Long ' "Turbidity"
    Dim wsRawLastRow As Long ' "RawTurbidity"

    ' I suggest you just name the sheets using the developer prop window
    'It cuts this whole part out as you can call them directly
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsRaw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

    ws1LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'lets say you are pasting to column A

    'ws1LastRow = ws1LastRow + 1
    'There you go the next writable cell row, this is wasted code though, see below you just increment when you need it

    wsRawLastRow = wsRaw.Cells(wsRaw.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'This method doesn't care if your data starts in C4

    'No formula needed, it is a straight "copy" here, actually faster as its an assignment
    ws1.Cells(ws1LastRow + 1, "A").Value = wsRaw.Cells(wsRawLastRow, "C").Value
    'the next open cell (defined by row) in your sheet 1 column is equal to the last row of your Raw Data sheet column

End Sub
```

Comment: Very similar to @BigBen 's comment, maybe fleshed out a little more.

Comment: Unfortunately even though this seems like good code the issue is that the analyst rarely do the calculations in order. They might need the data in row 5 of sheet 1 for one particular sample and than the next would be in row 35 on sheet one hence the active-cell need.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that the data in sheet one is not inputted in order. A person may need the data calculated to row 10 and the next calculation needs to be in row 20 hence the need to copy the data into the active cell.

This was my bad for not stating that in the initial post as it's the primary reason for this strange formula.